# List files without corresponding spec

Tags: ruby, linux, command-line

I've gotten a list of files using:

```
$ find ./app ./spec -name "*.rb" -print | sed 's!^.*/!!' | sort
```

And I receive a list like so:

```
thing.rb
thing_controller.rb
thing_search.rb
thing_search_spec.rb
thing_serializer.rb
thing_serializer_spec.rb
thing_spec.rb
```

From this list, I can see `thing.rb` has a corresponding `thing_spec.rb`, same goes for `thing_search.rb` and `thing_serializer.rb`. However, `thing_controller.rb` does not have a corresponding `thing_controller_spec.rb`

What could I pipe this list into in order for me to determine that `thing_controller.rb` does not have a corresponding `thing_controller_spec.rb`?

Comment: Tried adding a little more clarification. Out of this list, I would like to only print `thing_controller.rb` because that is the only file that does not have a corresponding `thing_controller_spec.rb`

Comment: This isn't a Ruby question.

Comment: I tagged it improperly. The first answer was Ruby so I didn't know if I should un-tag it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write something like below:

```
Dir["./app/**/*.rb"].each do |file|
  base      = File.basename(file, '.rb')
  spec_file = "./spec/#{base}_spec.rb"
  puts spec_file unless File.exist? spec_file
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a shell version I came up with taking from the original answer.

```
#! /usr/bin/env sh

app_dir=$1
spec_dir=$2
extension=$3

for file in $(find $app_dir -name "*${extension}" -print | sed "s!$app_dir*!!" | sed "s!$extension!!"); do
  spec_file="${spec_dir}${file}_spec${extension}"
  if [ ! -f  $spec_file ]; then
    echo $spec_file
  fi
done

# Usage: ./no_spec_finder ./app ./spec .rb
```